# storing multiple arrays within a struct in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I am trying to design a data structure in C where I can store multiple arrays possibly in a struct, where each of the arrays are of a different size. For example:

```
typedef struct task_list
{
  int total_tasks;
  unsigned int *task_array
 }task_list;

typedef struct node_list
{
  int total_nodes;
  task_list *array_node
 }node_list;
```

Therefore if I have 5 nodes, then `total_nodes` will be `5` and I wish to have 5 subsequent arrays namely `array_node[0]`, `array_node[1]` ... `array_node[4]`. Each of the arrays hold unsigned integers(tasks). The problem is each of these arrays hold a different number of tasks (`total_tasks` in struct `task_list`), therefore the size of each of the arrays will be different.

How do I create and allocate memory for each of these task array's? and what would be the best way to access them later?

Comment: "*... where I can store multiple arrays possibly in a struct, where each of the arrays are of a different size ...*", this is not possible as you worded it, however you could have an array of void pointers that points to different arrays of different sizes (and lengths).

Comment: Using the structures you have already, the only problem I see is `total_nodes` should be `total_task_lists`. Everything else is straight up if you think about it hard enough.

Answer (score 1):

If they are 1-D arrays, best way to allocate memory is through malloc.  Again, since they are 1-D you can access them via array notation, being careful no to exceed the bounds given by total_nodes and total_tasks.  Use free to free up arrays when deleting nodes.  If array nodes gets bigger, use realloc to make the array bigger and keep the old pointers in place.

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate a node_list, then allocate its array_node to hold 5 task_lists, then allocate each of the task_lists' task_arrays to hold a variable number of tasks (using `malloc(total_tasks) * sizeof(unsigned int))`).

Answer (score 0):

You should modify `node_list` so that it maintains an array of pointers to `task_list`:

```
typedef struct node_list
{
  int total_nodes;
  task_list **array_node;
 }node_list;
```

Now, if you need 5 task lists, you allocate room for 5 pointers to `task_list` first.

```
node_list n;
n.total_nodes = 5;
n.array_node = malloc(n.total_nodes * sizeof(task_list *));
```

Then, you iterate through each `array_node`, and allocate an appropriately sized `task_list`.

```
for (i = 0; i < n.total_nodes; ++i) {
    n.array_node[i] = allocate_task_list(task_list_size(i));
}
```

Then, to get to the `i`<sup>th</sup> `task_list`:

```
task_list *tl = n.array_node[i];
```